# Create a VHD file from a Linux disk

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vhd, dd

I have a disk containing CentOS 5.8 that was removed from a dead box. I would like to make a VHD file from this disk so I can run a virtual machine (instead of a new physical machine).

The Virtual Machine host is a Windows 2008 Server running VM Virtual Box.

I can't use disk2vhd (because this is a Windows program & Windows cannot 'see' the volume (it's attached by a USB adapter & the disk is visible in Disk Management)

I've tried the dd method specified in https://superuser.com/questions/410940/how-to-create-vhd-disk-image-from-a-linux-live-system, but the VHD's don't boot once created.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I have done a similar thing with QEMU, and it worked. Do you still have the raw image file? If you have a machine with QEMU, you could try to boot your image in QEMU, and if that works, convert the image to vhd using `qemu-img`.

Comment: I don't have the image file yet...

Comment: You've tried the [dd method](http://superuser.com/questions/410940/how-to-create-vhd-disk-image-from-a-linux-live-system), right? What are the results? Did you manage to get `myfile.dd` or `myfile.vhd`?

Comment: I got a myfile.dd which I converted to myfile.vhd - but it wouldn't book in VirtualBox...

Comment: That's why I ask if you can install QEMU. QEMU is able to boot from a device file (`qemu -hda /dev/sda`) or from a raw image (`qemu -hda myfile.dd`). This way you could see at which point your system loses the ability to boot.

Comment: QEMU is a Linux package - I need a Windows program...

Comment: You won't have to run your virtual machine in QEMU all the time. Once you get it booting you will export the image to VHD format using `qemu-img` and (hopefully) run it in Virtual box on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote that "QEMU is a Linux package", but is not fully true anymore.
One example of build of QEMU for Windows is as part of [WinSetupFromUSB 1.8](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/) program.

The other build of QEMU is in [qemu-img for Windows](https://cloudbase.it/qemu-img-windows/).

The third build of QEMU is as [mingw-w64-x86_64-qemu package](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-qemu?repo=mingw64).

**Convert in Windows a RAW PhysicalDrive2 to VHD**

```
qemu-img.exe convert -f raw -O vpc \\.\PhysicalDrive2 CentOS-5-8.vhd
```

**Convert in Linux a RAW sdb to QCOW2**

```
qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 /dev/sdb fitsu_MKB3021LT.qcow2
```

**Convert a QCOW2, RAW, VMDK or VDI image to VHDX**

```
qemu-img.exe convert source.img -O vhdx -o subformat=dynamic dest.vhdx
```

**Convert a QCOW2, RAW, VMDK or VDI image to VHD**

```
qemu-img.exe convert source.img -O vpc -o subformat=dynamic dest.vhd
```

Comment: If I zerofill first the disk via dd will the process go bit faster? I mean if disk is 40G it will take some time

Comment: Tip: Convert to qcow2 first, then convert from qcow2 -> vhdx to compress away zeros. Before that, use zerofree to explicitly write zeros into an ext* filesystem.

Comment: How do I know on windows that my raw drive is PhysicalDrive2 ?

Comment: @felixyadomi you can use `Get-PhysicalDisk` on powershell to get the number.

Comment: On Ubuntu (and presumably Debian), the linux package containing "qemu-img" is "qemu-utils" and therefore can be installed with the command "apt install qemu-utils".